# Force of constraint for particle constrained to a surface

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

In Goldstein's Classical Mechanics, he wrote

> If a particle is constrained to move on a surface, the force of constraint is perpendicular to the surface.

Why must the force of constraint be perpendicular to the surface?

Intuitively I think that to keep a small bead moving on the surface of the sphere, I would have to press the bead down onto the sphere to keep it there. But I can also exert the force at an angle to the surface normal to keep the ball moving on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: By sideways force, do you mean force tangent to the surface?

Comment: i mean maybe like 45 degrees to the tangent surface

Comment: @NLP I put a bit more thought into it and this is what I understand now: A force of constraint perpendicular to the surface will prevent any momentum gain in the direction perpendicular to the tangent surface. So the particle can only move in the tangent surface and hence is constrained to the surface.

Comment: I was typing my answer... you beat me to it! Well done. Do you want to answer your own question for posterity?

Comment: @NLP ok! thanks for the help. You mention of the "tangent" gave me the hint to think in the right direction haha.

Comment: @NJP Oops, didn't see this comment, so I might have inadvertently stolen your answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: @probably_someone No problem, I was going to give it away to OP anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the constraint force was not perpendicular to the surface, then it would have some component tangent to the surface. Suppose for a moment that the particle constrained to the surface is otherwise a free particle. Since it's a free particle, if it's stationary at $t=0$, it will be stationary for all time. But if there's a tangential component of the constraint force at some point, then an initially-stationary free particle placed at that point would spontaneously start to move, which violates the assumption that it was a free particle and generates a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

A force of constraint perpendicular to the surface will prevent any momentum gain in the direction perpendicular to the tangent surface.

So the particle can only move in the tangent surface and is hence constrained to the surface.